# Section Of Website On Another Server

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, website

I have a vendor developing a new section of my company's website and the vendor will host and maintain this section of the website which is a different server than my main website.  The vendor suggested a subdomain for this new section of the website.  However, I feel strongly about not using a subdomain and keeping it as part of the main domain.

The main website is a windows and the vendors server is a windows server.

Is it hard to setup a section of my website hosted on the vendors windows server, but keeping this section a part of the main domain (not a subdomain) on my windows server?

How do I communicate to the vendor what they need to do in the server environment to make this happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: " However, I feel strongly about not using a subdomain" You may want to explain that. Is it backed by some facts or just feelings? Because otherwise this is the natural and simplest solution to your use case. Anything else (like proxying) will have performances and/or security implications. The subdomain case may just have security implications related to cookies.

Comment: @Patrick Thank you for the response.  The reason is that I've spent years building SEO site authority to my main domain.  It helps a ton for search ranking on this consumer website.  For a subdomain I have to build site authority all over again for the subdomain and it will hurt this section of my site.  If this section of my site was on the main domain the authority I've built would carry through the new section of the site.  Without hosting this section of my site on my server is there any other options I should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serve contents on different servers using the same FQDN, you'll need to put a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) in front of them; only a reverse proxy can actually parse HTTP requests and forward them to different servers based on what is being requested.

A reverse proxy can receive requests for, say, `www.example.com` and then apply rules like "send all requests to server A but if someone asks for `www.example.com/somepath` send it to server B".

This role is usually performed by a dedicated device (or server), but some firewalls have built-in reverse proxy functions.

If you don't already have a reverse proxy in front of your web site, it will probably be a lot easier to just use a subdomain and point it to the other server, like the vendor suggested.